# How to import/merge js files based on references

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, typescript, gulp

In my MVC 6 app, as a replacement for the older js/css bundling & minification-system, I want to produce 1 javascript file that I can reference in my HTML. This javascript file is page/action-specific so I can't just concat all .js files in a folder.

With CSS (using LESS) I already managed to do this by using @import, the created .css file will then be a combination of the original .less file plus all the imports merged into 1 file. Now I'm trying to do the same with my .js files.

In GULP I can easily minify each seperate file, and place them in the correct folders, but I don't know how to merge them with the right files. I dont want to create a gulp task for each file/js telling what to concat.

I thought about using TypeScript to reference other js files and then compiling them with GULP to one file but this seems a bit harder. I'm open to other frameworks that can manage this as well.

In typescript using ///reference or import module doesn't actually result in an import when compiling like it does with LESS.

So for example, consider the following js **or typescript**-structure

```
scripts/common/master.js (or .ts etc.)
scripts/maincontroller/index.js (uses master.js)
scripts/maincontroller/support.js (uses master.js)

desired result after compile/merge/concat with gulp:

wwwroot/js/common/master.js (unchanged because nothing referenced)
wwwroot/js/maincontroller/index.js (concat with master.js)
wwwroot/js/maincontroller/support.js (concat with master.js)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to achieve this by using http://browserify.org/ with GULP. I can use 'require('master.js')' in my index.js and browserify will concat the 2 files together. Not the easiest task but it seems to work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting design. It actually means that I don't benefit as much from my browser caching, because I end up downloading `master.js` three times (but in three different files) - and that is just based on the three files in your example.

If you have a large number of files, keep everything as individual files and use a module loader, such as RequireJS. This way, `master.js` is cached after the first page and they only need to load `index.js` on the next page (and so on).

If you don't have a large number of files, bundle them into a single file and load it late in the page.

Comment: well, if you visit both index and support, you will load the master-section twice that is true. But that will always happen when bundling files, the index.js and support.js itself will be cached though. I feel like using require.js adds a lot of extra code per index.js etc.

Comment: You don't re-load the script on every page when you bundle files - the bundled file is fetched once, then it is cached. Using RequireJS will require zero extra code. Target AMD or UMD modules when compiling and the output will be correctly translated for you. When ECMAScript modules arrive, you can just switch the module kind and the browser will perform the module loading.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, that the bundled file is fetched once and cached, BUT there is 1 (partially different) bundled file per page, so on each different page, a new bundle has to be loaded. I will look into requirejs to see if I can get it to work :)

Comment: By the way, from what I get from you is that bundling is actually counterproductive in terms of performance? So I should generally try to avoid it to enable the caching of separate files.

Comment: If you bundle everything into one file, it works quite well (until the file becomes too large for this technique, as som 1M line TypeScript apps have). If you create lots of small bundles you actually get caught between the "correct" answer for smaller applications (one big bundle) and the "correct" answer for bigger applications (async loading of modules as they are needed).

Answer (score 0):

GO to solution explorer and right click on your project and click add references.

Then go and browse your references files. :)

sry for bad english!

Comment: its not about adding references to the project, but importing js code into other js files.